# Login screen built in C#.NET not working on Mac

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have a web application that starts at a login screen. My registered users start with a default password, and when they try to use it they are redirected to a page where they can set their own password, along with other information.

I have discovered that this default login doesn't work on Macs for some reason: a user can enter his credentials, but then his input for the password just disappears, and his browser doesn't navigate anywhere. However, once a user has gone through the initial login process, they can login with no issue. I'm hoping someone can shed some light on how I can make my login screen "Mac-friendly."

The user enters his username and password into standard text boxes, and clicks a button:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="userName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="passWd" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="loginBtn" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="loginBtn_Click" /><p />
```

Below is the code of the loginBtn_Click event function:

```
if (failPanel.Visible) { failPanel.Visible = false; }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("command", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", userName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", passWd.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (con)
        {
            try
            {
                using (cmd)
                {
                    using (da)
                    {
                        using (dt)
                        {
                            da.Fill(dt);

                            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] = dt;
                                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[4].ToString()) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[5].ToString()))
                                {
                                    Response.Redirect("Security.aspx");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                failPanel.Visible = true;
                                failLbl.Text = "Incorrect User name or Password";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                failPanel.Visible = true;
                failLbl.Text = "Unable to process login:<p/>" + ex.Message + "<p/>Please notify IT";
            }
        }
```

That "command" stored procedure just checks a database to see if the user has completed registration or not.

So as you can see, this is a straightforward thing, but it doesn't work in iOS Safari or Firefox. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any hints on the console of FF/Safari? Is the login page already stripped down the bare inputs? Did you try debugging by running your page from FF? Does a PostBack happen or does it rather feel like just the password input is emptied client side? Does it work from FF on Windows and/or Linux?

Comment: @Filburt Yes, the site works with no problems on Windows. We don't have any Linux users, so I can't say if it works there. No clues as to the problem from the FF dev console -- no errors showing up, so I can't say if the error is client or server side, but it's so quick it's likely client.